# Return right content searching a substring in dictionary- Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, string, postgresql, where-clause

I need the value of substring depending the string filtered using Postgresql.

For example:

**Table Users**

```
{'Name': 'Eric', 'Age':'29', 'Weight': '80kg'}

{'Age':'41','Name': 'Alex', 'Weight': '100kg'}

{'Weight': '90kg','Age':'18', 'Name': 'Jason'}
```

- The order of the fields is not organized, the position is not fixed because the length of strings;
- This result is a unique JSON field.

So, I need the value depending the string I search, like:

**Searched string (Dummy example):**

SELECT "Age" FROM Users WHERE Name = 'Jason'

Results:   '18'

**OR**

SELECT "Age" FROM Users WHERE Name = 'Alex'

Results:   '41'

Probably I will use the function Right (https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/right-function.php) with some other function. I tried to use substring (https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php) too together, but do not fit in this case.

Comment: What is the name and the datatype of that column?

Comment: Hi GMB. It's user_return and the datatype is a JSON. It help answer your doubt?

Comment: [PostgreSQL anti-patterns](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string methods!

Since you are dealing with a JSON datatype, you can just use [Postgres JSON accessor operator `->>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to access the value of a given key:

```
select user_return  ->> 'Age' from Users where user_return ->> 'Name' = 'Alex'
```

Note: keys in a JSON object have no special ordering whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks GMB. It's worked. 

Only one case do not worked because the JSON is complex with other JSONs inside.